# How to map/route OData endpoint in ASP .NET5

Tags: odata, asp.net-core

I was wondering if anybody knew the ASP .NET 5 equivalent to this OData mapping code, as there is no `HttpConfiguration` object now?  I am specifically interested in how to reproduce the `config.MapODataServiceRoute` functionality.  Thanks.

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // New code:
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [source code](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/Extensions/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs) for `MapODataServiceRoute`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link - it looks pretty straightforward so I'll take a stab at implementing it this weekend.